# Spring Boot 2 Async making the call but not returning a response

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have my async half-way working. The call is being made async but when the result is returned it doesn't hit the code I have.

Spring boot application class has `@EnableAsync` on it.

```
@Service
public class MyService() {

    private MyClient client;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(MyClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public String callHttpService() {
        Future<String> asyncResponse = client.submitOrder("test");

        String response = null;

        if(asyncResponse.isDone()) {

            // client call made and result comes back but never comes in here
            response = asyncResponse.get();
        }

        return response;
     }
}

@Component
public class MyClient() extends RestClient {

    @Async
    public Future<String> submitOrder(String request) {
         String response;
         try {
            response = super.invoke(request, HttpMethod.POST);
         } catch(RestInvocationException e) {
            .....
         }

          return new AsycResult<>(response);
    }
}
```

I've even tried another variation of my client response where I do:`response = new AsyncResult<>(super.invoke(request, HttpMethod.POST));  return response;`

I don't understand why once I make the call and get the response it's not going inside my `.isDone()` block.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until your request is done, like this:

```
while (true) {
    if (asyncResponse.isDone()) {
        response = asyncResponse.get();
        break;
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

When you check the `isDone` result of the `Future` result it could be false, because your request is made asynchronously and it takes some time to make it.

Just to note, the `isDone` method doesn't block the execution until the job is done, it just returns immediately whether your job is done or not.

Comment: I saw this in an example by baeldung and I thought it was just for demonstration purposes. Seems kind of hacky to have a while loop and Thread.sleep. On the other hand I haven't really seen any other examples online.

Comment: Yes, it's just for example purposes, how it's done with multiple threads running asynchronously. The way you use it, you don't really need to do your request asynchronously, because you want to have a response immediately. You need async call if you don't know how long it will take until your job is done and you don't want to block your program execution for that time. In that case you get a `Future` as a result and can use it for example in some scheduled job, which will periodically check whether your job is done and perform some action, when it is

Comment: Yeah what I want is a future so the code is unblocked. I want to make an async call to a REST endpoint but not halt the application. When the response comes back I want to do something else but the application should not stop.

Comment: For that you have to make some service or method, which will be responsible for that, and you don't have to do it in the same method, making a request. When you make a request you have to add a Future returned by async call to some shared collection(for example), and make a method, which is running periodically (once in a minute may be) and which job is to iterate this shared Future collection and make something with the response, when it's ready. It's not the way, which is usually shown in simple examples

Comment: Or you can try to do what you want with the CompletableFuture https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html